# you heard me vs did you hear me?

Tags: differences

What's the difference?

> A: What is your plan for tonight?
>   B: I am dating Jane.
>   A: What did you say?
>
> B: You heard me?

or

> B: Did you hear me?

Both are ok, in this case?

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "You heard me" is a challenge.  It means "don't pretend that you didn't hear what I said because I know otherwise."

"Did you hear me?" is inapt.  A has already asked B "What did you say?"  It's clear that A is claiming that he didn't hear B.

"Did you not hear me?" expresses B's irritation or astonishment at having not been heard.